# Position dots in certain sectors of a circle starting in the center

Tags: php, javascript, geometry, positioning

The problem is to position dots in certain sectors of a circle starting in the center.

```
$dot[1] = secto12;
$dot[2] = secto6;
$dot[3] = secto8;
$dot[4] = secto2;
$dot[5] = secto8;
$dot[6] = secto3;
etc...
```

[image]

We could use PHP or javascript.

I can imagine a function to mimic a centripetal force. Or maybe some procedure of  analytic geometry. Or whatever...

Any idea is welcome.
THX.-

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you want them to act like marbles, that can slide sideways into a depression, or like snowflakes, that stick where they touch?

Comment: You can calculate your sectors by splitting 360 degrees over 12, so first sector would be from 0 to 30 degrees. But more clarification would help.

Comment: I have a lot of dots that I need positioning in the circle (each one in a certain sector)

@Beta: Yes, like marbles. But I only said that to give an idea. The main proposal of this procedure is to fill (certain) sectors using the available space the best possible (that's why I start in the center). The final result can be like the attached image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The solution that I used is a little complicated. And is not generic. We need calculate certain things manually ($factor (variations of angles) and $dots (amount of dots to draw on certain radius)).

But I want to give the basic ideas for someone else that needs something similar:

**1**.- We use the equation that find a point given:
0.- a center point: ($x0, $y0)
1.- a radius: $r
2.- an angle: $angle

```
$x = floor($x0 + $r * sin($angle * pi() / 180));
$y = floor($y0 + $r * -cos($angle * pi() / 180));
```

**2**.-We plot dots (certain amount of dots) changing the radius and the angle
The amount of dots depends of the radius. More radius more dots. We will need define a function that draw dots sector by sector.

**3**.- We need calculate certain things manually ($factor (variations of angles) and $dots (amount of dots to draw on certain radius)). Here it is:

```
if ($r >= 90) {
    $dots = 4;
    $factor = 12.1;
}
if ($r >= 100) {
    $dots = 4;
    $factor = 12.4;
}
if ($r >= 110) {
    $dots = 5;
    $factor = 8.4;
}
if ($r >= 120) {
    $dots = 6;
    $factor = 6.2;
}
if ($r >= 130) {
    $dots = 7;
    $factor = 5.2;
}
if ($r >= 140) {
    $dots = 8;
    $factor = 4.4;
}
if ($r >= 150) {
    $dots = 9;
    $factor = 3.8;
}
if ($r >= 200) {
    $dots = 10;
    $factor = 3.40;
}
if ($r >= 220) {
    $dots = 11;
    $factor = 3.0;
}
```

Those are the main ideas to  solve this, in this tricky way.

**4**.- Obviously this code (inside a function) must be called inside nested loops (3 in my case)

```
function plot($sector, $start) {
    ....
}
```

$start is the angle from start drawing: 0, 30, 60,..., 330

**???** OK, here is the function. Enjoy:

```
function plot($sector, $start) {

    static $static;
    $x0 = 0;
    $y0 = 0;

    if ( ! isset($static[$sector])) {
        /*
         * factor: related to the amplitude of the arc on which dots are drawn. (11.1 -> 3.0)
         * dots: how many dots draw towards the right. (3 -> 10)
         * r: radius in pixels. (60 -> 240)
         * jstatic: save last position of dot drawn.
         *
         */
        $static[$sector]['factor'] = 11.1;
        $static[$sector]['dots'] = 4;
        $static[$sector]['r'] = 60;
        $static[$sector]['jstatic'] = 0;
    }

    $factor = $static[$sector]['factor'];
    $dots = $static[$sector]['dots'];
    $r = $static[$sector]['r'];
    $jstatic = $static[$sector]['jstatic'];

    for ($j = $jstatic; $j < $dots; $j ++ ) {
        if ($r >= 90) {
            $dots = 4;
            $factor = 12.1;
        }
        if ($r >= 100) {
            $dots = 4;
            $factor = 12.4;
        }
        if ($r >= 110) {
            $dots = 5;
            $factor = 8.4;
        }
        if ($r >= 120) {
            $dots = 6;
            $factor = 6.2;
        }
        if ($r >= 130) {
            $dots = 7;
            $factor = 5.2;
        }
        if ($r >= 140) {
            $dots = 8;
            $factor = 4.4;
        }
        if ($r >= 150) {
            $dots = 9;
            $factor = 3.8;
        }
        if ($r >= 200) {
            $dots = 10;
            $factor = 3.40;
        }
        if ($r >= 220) {
            $dots = 11;
            $factor = 3.0;
        }

        if ($j == $dots - 1) {
            $j = 0;
            $jstatic = 0;
            // increase radius (by 10 pixels --each dot have 7 pixel of diameter) to the next arc.
            $r = $r + 10;
        }

        // stop if circumference is reached.
        if ($r > 240)
            break;

        $angle = $factor * $j + $start;

        // (x, y) is...
        $x = floor($x0 + $r * sin($angle * pi() / 180));
        $y = floor($y0 + $r * -cos($angle * pi() / 180));

        $pos['x'] = $x;
        $pos['y'] = $y;

        $jstatic ++;

        // save all dat by each sector
        $static[$sector]['factor'] = $factor;
        $static[$sector]['dots'] = $dots;
        $static[$sector]['r'] = $r;
        $static[$sector]['jstatic'] = $jstatic;

        /*
         * only for debugging:
         * counting how many dots are drawn
          static $countDots = 0;
          global $countDots;
          $countDots++;
         */
        return $pos;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two halves to this: the math of positioning the dots, and the rendering engine to display circle + dots.

The first half is an interesting math puzzle which is probably beyond the scope of a simple Stack Overflow question. But once you set up a rendering system, you can easily experiment until you achieve what you're looking for.

For the second half, I suggest looking into [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com), a Javascript library for easily drawing shapes and other vector graphics using SVG.

Comment: For the second part I can use PHP: `imagefilledellipse($image, $dot['x'], $dot['y'], 7, 7, $textColor)` Is the first part that I need some suggest. Indeed I have an idea for determinate (x,y) for the starting dot on each sector (after that is easy) but I want to share this problem because is common that someone else have a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of finding where a dot comes to rest is tricky, but I think I'd approach it this way (with experiments along the way, to back up intuition):

1. Pick a starting theta at random, within the desired bin. This is the location of the dot at the "top" (the edge of the circle).

   For each dot already in the bin, determine its (angular) distance to the chosen fall line. It's then simple geometry to determine which dot the falling dot will encounter first, and where the falling dot will be when this happens. This is enough for snowflakes.

   Marbles can slide; look at the neighbors of the stationary dot, on the side on which the falling dot touched. We can determine which neighbor the sliding dot will encounter first. Watch the walls. (We will not worry about bouncing, dislodging stationary dots or becoming airborne-- the sim doesn't have to be that good.)

   If the sliding dot makes contact with the neighbor on the opposite side, it stops. If it makes contact on the same side, it is now free to slide along the neighbor-- we must repeat the previous step.

P.S. This will give a pretty good packing, which is probably all you need. The *optimal* packing is really hard to find.

Comment: Yes, I am thinking in draw dots along geometrics arcs. BTW, I put this question in [mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/57024/the-problem-is-to-position-these-dots-in-certain-sectors-of-a-circle-starting-in) I like how (clearly) you put it in your step #4. Yes, that's the right way. But it must be done over concentric arcs. So this involved 3 equations (one arc and 2 radius), Aha, dropping the keyboard and going to buy a pencil (years without seeing one :) Thanks. I'll put the whole solution when ready...

Answer (score 0):

Constructing a physics engine to simulate the circles and walls is, while probably more involved than you were hoping for, not terribly difficult. If you use Verlet integration to control the balls location and speed, collisions between balls and between balls and the walls of a segment become trivially easy to resolve - you just move the offending balls the minimum distance required to resolve the collision. Collision response - loss of speed, etc, is handled implicitly.

You'd set up your system such that the balls were attracted to the center of the circle, and constrained to stay:

1. Some distance from the center
2. Within their segment
3. Some distance away from other balls

A simple physical simulation will provide a good packing for the balls, and you'll get a cool-looking animation for free.

[This](http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/nsp/course/15-869/2006/papers/jakobsen.htm) is a good explanation of the approach (everything up to the "Rigid Bodies" section is appropriate)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple to solve using sfc or a hilbert curve or gray code. Actually a hilbert curve is hamiltonian traversal of a graph and such generate a gray code. U can search the net about gray code and how its used in properly defining sectors on a harddisk. If use the hilbert curve to solve the problem its constraints is that the circle has to cover a plane of power of 2. The othet problem is that it is only an approximaation but a very good one.